# Form submit button event is not captured when keyboard is opened

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3

Hi I have a problem regarding a cordova app that runs on ios 7.

On all out form fields when the keyboard is opened we can not click any buttons on the screen.

If for example I would want to click the login button on the login screed instead of the keyboard go button I would have to first tap to close the keyboard and then tap again for the button to take the event.

I am using knockout for data-bind this is my html:

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }">
            <input type="text" id="username" data-bind="value: userLoginModel.userName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: localization.__LK_Login_Email_Place_Holder__ }" autocapitalize="off"/>
            <span class="login-error-message" data-bind="validationMessage: userLoginModel.userName"></span>
        </li>
        <li data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }">
            <input type="password" id="password" data-bind="value: userLoginModel.password, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: { placeholder: localization.__LK_Login_Password_Place_Holder__ }" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
            <span class="login-error-message" data-bind="validationMessage: userLoginModel.password"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" data-bind="value: localization.__LK_Login_Submit_Button__, click: events.submitLoginForm" id="submitLoginForm" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

How can I make the button to take the event if the keyboard is opened?

Comment: Why you use the event click instead of the [event submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit)?

Comment: it does not make a difference which one I use the event works but only after the keyboard is closed I have tryed with both

Comment: Have you tried to add `action="#"` in the form tag?